# Como puedo hacer para que mi insert no guarde datos duplicados php y mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

como puedo implementar una condición que no me permita agregar registros con el mismo nombre de usuario: ejemplo si el nombre de usuario prueba1 esta registrado no deberia permitir guardar otro usuario con el mismo nombre.

este es mi insert:

```
<script src="sweet/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<body bgcolor="#131313" style="color:#131313;font-family: sans-serif;">
<?php
  include "conexiones.php";

$usuario_nom=$_POST['usuario_nom'];
$nombre_comple=$_POST['nombre_comple'];
$apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
$emailusuario=$_POST['emailusuario'];
$pasusuario=$_POST['pasusuario'];
$estatus=$_POST['estatus'];


   {
       $sql="INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario_nom,nombre_comple,apellidos,emailusuario,pasusuario,estatus) 
       VALUES ('$usuario_nom','$nombre_comple','$apellidos','$emailusuario','$pasusuario','$estatus')";
       $res=mysqli_query($cn,$sql);


       if($res){

           echo"<script type='text/javascript'>         

    swal({
        icon:  'success',
        title: 'Perfecto!',
        text:  'Usuario agregado correctamente!'
            }).then(function() {
                window.location = 'usuarios.php';
            });

        </script>";

        }else{
            die("Error".mysqli_error($cn));
        }

    }

?>
</body>
```

Comment: En tu tabla donde planeas guardar los datos, deberías poner el atributo `UNIQUE` en la columna deseada de esta forma el propio motor de bd no va a permitir ingresos duplicados

Comment: También serviría, pero también seria bueno tener un mensaje que le indique al administrador que el nombre de usuario ya esta en uso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr lo que deseas, a nivel de código deberías:

- Hacer una consulta a la tabla deseada con un `COUNT` basándose en un criterio para filtrar, es decir con un `WHERE` buscarás establecer un conteo de todas las filas que coincidan en una columna con el valor dinámico que te llega en una variable
- Si la consulta anterior retorna 0 entonces el registro no existe
- Si el registro anterior retorna 1 entonces el registro ya existe y no debería permitirse el ingreso de dicho valor

Entonces:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tuTabla WHERE columna = '".$valor."'");

$conteo = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

if($conteo > 0) 
{
     echo "El registro ya existe";
} else {
     $insercion = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO...............");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No manejo php pero si quieres que no se repita un campo debes agregar la clausula UNIQUE en el campo que no quieres que se repita:

```
CREATE TABLE Ejemplo(
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        Usuario VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE, # Al agregar UNIQUE aqui no se repitira el usuario
        Contraseña VARCHAR(15)
    )
```